# SUMIFS with Multiple Date Range Criteria and Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am trying to calculate the amount of collection for a single "Operation Code" but within a certain date range so I try the following function but it doesn't work , It calculates all the collections in this date range for all "Operation codes" not for the selected one.

[image: Complex SUMIFS With Multiple Date Ranges and Criteria]

I use this function :

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($D$8:$D$10>=B1)*($D$8:$D$10<=B2)*($C$8:$C$10=E2));SUMIFS(G8:I10;F8:H10;">="&B4;F8:H10;"<="&B5);0)
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem

Thanks in advance for your help .

Comment: Welcome to SO. The expected output is 90? Can you explain with more details why? Because your dates range right now is whole 2019 year, and your formula is summing up exactly that, returning 120.

Comment: Hello Sir, The Expected Output is 90 based on the "Operation Code" number 5015-10 which I want to Calculate it only not all the "Operation Codes"

Comment: 5015-10 and the collection dates table data are completely unrelated. You need more description

Comment: "Operation Code" number 5015-10 is related to date 30/09/2019. That date has not relation at all with the dates of the collection you want to sum up (first date is 01/10/2019 and second one is 01/11/2019). So that's why I'm asking what is the logic behind your calculation, because I can't see it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, If your collection code are related to amounts in **same row** then you can use this:

[image]

My formula is:

```
=INDEX($G:$G;MATCH($E$2;$C:$C;0))+INDEX($I:$I;MATCH($E$2;$C:$C;0))
```

It returns 90, as you can see.

If I change the Operation code to 5015-11, it returns 30.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**: If you need to filter by dates, then try with SUMIFS

[image]

```
=SUMIFS(G8:G10;F8:F10;">="&B4;F8:F10;"<="&B5;C8:C10;E2)+SUMIFS(I8:I10;H8:H10;">="&B4;H8:H10;"<="&B5;C8:C10;E2)
```

If I change, let's say, collection date to->31/10/2019, I get this:

[image]

It returns only 50, because the amount 40 is related to 01/11/2019 and that date is outside the range set up.

If the logic behind this process is different, please, post more details and explain it.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I want to say for a specific "Operation code" calculate the amount of collections within the collection date range for a specific range of due dates based on the due date of the "Operation Code", I hope this will explains that for you, Thanks in advance.

Comment: This helps, but my data is so large with a 1000+ Operation Codes and 40 columns of collection amounts, it will be so hard to make 40 addition functions

Comment: And also I have to take in consideration the due date range to be more specific for the report.